# How to display recently created pages on page using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Lot of articles showing how to display on homepage, but what about on another page such as a page?

This is what I have in my controller file:

```
public function page($slug)
{
    $page = MenuPage::where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail();
    return view('pages.page', compact('page'));

}
```

This code controls the list of pages in the page section in the backend:

```
public function index()
{
    $pages = MenuPage::all();
    return view('admin-SchoolDir.menu-pages.index', compact('pages'));
}
```

page.blade.php has my page layout code.

Curious to know what code to put into the controller file and what to put in the view file?

I saw this code in one article for the controller file to display recent posts:

```
 $recentPosts = Post::take(5)->latest()->get();
```

but where would I put that code at?

In the backend where I manage the list of pages, this is the code used to show the list of pages:

```
                        @foreach($pages as $page)

                          <tr>

                            <td>{{ $page->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $page->menu_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $page->title }}</td>
                          </tr>
                       @endforeach
```

If I put that code into my page layout, I get an "Undefined variable: pages" error.

Comment: Yes, `$pages` is `not` defined in the blade file. Did you pass it to this blade file from anywhere?

Comment: but in the backend where I manage the pages, it works fine. No error.  I have a separate blade file for the backend.

Comment: In your backend where you manage the pages, you will have a separate `route` and probably a separate `controller method` to do it, in which you would have passed `$pages` to the blade file. Here you are managing a page layout, and according to your controller method, you haven't passed $pages this time as you showed in your post.

Comment: The controller code I posted above that says MenuPage is the one that manages the page section of the backend and it also manages the page layout on the frontend.

Comment: I've posted the code up.  It says public function index.

Comment: If I put `@foreach($page as $page)`, I get a "Trying to get property of non-object " error.

Comment: In `public function page($slug)` which is used for the single page layout, you have `compact('page')` and in the blade view file which is `page.blade.php`, you are trying to access `$pages`. So since you didn't pass any `$pages` from controller to this view file, it is `undefined`

Comment: @vivek_23 - look at the comment I posted above yours.

Comment: I read that. What does `$page = MenuPage::where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail();` give you? Probably it should give you a stdClass Object.  `@foreach($page as $page)` expects `$page` to be an array of objects here which it isn't.

Comment: I have no idea what `$page = MenuPage::where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail();` gives me.  My pages are setup so that I can customize the URLs and make them SEO friendly so a "slug" was created as part of the page.

Comment: Do a `echo "<pre>";var_dump($page);` to check what `$page = MenuPage::where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail();` gives you.

Comment: I get a re-creation of the page (the page pretty much duplicates itself).  But where the page title should be, it says some weird stuff.

Comment: object(App\MenuPage)#323 (26) { ["fillable":protected]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "title" [1]=> string(9) "menu_name" [2]=> string(4) "body" [3]=> string(4) "slug" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCount":protected]=> array(0) { } ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) ["attributes":protected]=> array(7) { ["id"]=>

Comment: Any ideas @vivek_23 ?

Comment: Ok, can you let me know whether you wan to show `page id`,'page menu_name` and `page title` in single page layout as well?

Comment: I just want the title to be shown.

Comment: You mean that single page title or all page titles in this single page layout?

Comment: it should basically be the page titles of all the recently creates pages.  so maybe the last 5 pages that were created.

Comment: I have added my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function page($slug)
{
    $page  =  MenuPage::where('slug',$slug)->firstOrFail();
    $pages =  MenuPage::take(5)->latest()->get();
    return view('pages.page', compact('page','pages'));
}
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing compact 'page' not 'pages'

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the controller, when you retrieve data from database.

```
public function index()
{
    $pages = MenuPage::latest()->get();
    return view('admin-SchoolDir.menu-pages.index', compact('pages'));
}
```

You should avoid business logic into views.

Comment: Typo sorry.. fixed